# Shortcode to Change Text on Slider Layer

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

On my WordPress site, I have a standard image slider with a layer of text on top.  I would like to change the text if a person is an admin.  The trouble is I don't know what the filter should be.  What I'm using now is

```
 function replace_text($text) {
      if ( is_admin() ) {
        $text = str_replace('Welcome', 'Registration Now Open', $text);
        return $text;
 }
}
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text');
```

But 'the_content' doesn't target the layer so nothing changes.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?  Thanks.

Comment: `is_admin` means, "you are using the wp-admin" not "You are an admin" - use `if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )`

Comment: Right. Thanks. Still need to find out if I can replace the text

Comment: Where do you get that slider and its text? Is it coming from a plugin? If so, what's the name of that plugin? Does it have a config menu on your admin panel? It'd help if you could edit your question and include the `html structure of your slider`.

Comment: You don't have enough information here to help.

Comment: Meta Slider Pro is the name of the plugin..it has a config menu and you can put in one text..but there is no conditional text (one of a logged-in user and one of a non-logged-in user.